# count days with referring staff_id in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[image]

I want to count the total number of days by referring to the staff ID column. For example, staff_id number 6 has a total of 13 days, staff_id number 7 has a total of 7 days, and so on. How can I achieve this result? I have tried using DAX, but I still can't get the result because I am a beginner in using Power BI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pull **staff_id** and **transaction_date** onto a table visual and make sure the aggregation for **staff_id** is "Don't summarize" and for **transaction_date** it's "Count":

[image]

Comment: it turns out that my data is in a hierarchy. so the day column cannot be calculated. do you know how to make the day column count?

Comment: Use COUNT( 'Table'[Day] )

Comment: bro, please help me. you can see what I mean in the other answers. I sent a picture in the other answer column so that it can make it easier for you to help me. once again I apologize for bothering you. I hope you and your family are always healthy

Comment: okay bro with my pleasure. very thanks brader you done help me.